# R: attach() what if a variable has a space in it?

Tags: r

My dataset is really simple (clouds.txt). It has the following format.

```
"seeded clouds" "unseeded clouds"
129.6 26.1
31.4 26.3
2745.6 87
489.1 95
etc. etc.
```

I used the following code.

```
clouds = read.table("materials/clouds.txt", header=TRUE)
attach(clouds)
```

How do I now use the variables "seeded clouds" and "unseeded clouds" ?

I looked at the `attach()` function in the R manual and via Google. I also tried typing in seeded_clouds, seededclouds and seeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-syntactic variable names can be used by placing them within backticks:

```
`my variable` <- 3
`my variable`
## 3
```

Note that when the data is read in using `read.table` it will change the column names to syntactic variable names (unless `check.names = FALSE` argument of `read.table` is used).

```
Lines <- '"seeded clouds" "unseeded clouds"
129.6 26.1
31.4 26.3
2745.6 87
489.1 95
'
clouds <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
clouds$seeded.clouds    

clouds2 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
clouds2$"seeded clouds"
clouds2[["seeded clouds"]]
```

One can use back ticks in other contexts such as when using `with`, `transform`, etc.

```
transform(clouds2, diff = `seeded clouds` - `unseeded clouds`)

dif <- with(clouds2, `seeded clouds` - `unseeded clouds`)

plot(`seeded clouds` ~ `unseeded clouds`, clouds2)
```

`attach(clouds2)` can be used in which case the variables can be referenced using backticks but normally `attach` is only used interactively and is discouraged for programming.

Comment: Thanks for the background info. I know that attach() normally is not reccommended.

Answer (score 3):

```
`seeded clouds`
`unseeded clouds`
```

edit: although it seems the OP didn't need this format, this should work for someone who does need this (i.e. someone who has decided to use spaces in a column name)

```
x = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2: 11)
colnames(x) = c("a column","another column")
attach(x)
"a column"
#[1] "a column"
`a column`
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Sorry, I forgot to consider the given data as a text file rather than the actual data frame.

Comment: Thanks, but that will deliver a string. But I just found my answer :)

Comment: The above works for me, but note that it's using ` rather than the usual quote symbol ' or ". For me, it's the symbol above tab and to the left of 1 on the keyboard.

Comment: ah k, i copied/pasted your answer into my environment. It could very well be that my environment can't handle it, since I'm using Knitr on sharelatex.

Comment: That's the correct answer in case the data.frame has columns names "seeded clouds" and "unseeded clouds", but as correctly pointed out in other answers, read.table automatically replaces spaces with dots...

Comment: yeah, sorry OP, I had missed that you were showing file contents rather than the output of the loaded data.frame, which I should have noticed.

Answer (score 2):

`read.table()` will convert the spaces to dots. You should have `seeded.clouds` in your environment.

Comment: ha! you beat me to it :)

Comment: You can switch that off with `check.names=FALSE` but I don't recommend it :-) See the (long) help for `read.table`.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled the problem in a wrong way. Once I typed clouds, I saw the following.

```
##    seeded.clouds unseeded.clouds
## 1          129.6           26.10
## 2           31.4           26.30
## 3         2745.6           87.00
```

Needless to say, the answers are seeded.clouds and unseeded.clouds.

Comment: you should have used names or str after reading in the data and the answer would have been obvious